# How to Run a Function after press Enter key on Select List in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Select List and I want when changes option select list and  Enter Key pressed the run jquery function.
This is my code:

```js
$("#productlist").keydown(function(){
  
  //for example 
  
  alert('Enter Pressed');
  });
```

```html
<select id="productlist">
<option id="1" value="1">1<option>
<option id="2" value="2">2<option>
<option id="3" value="3">3<option>
<option id="4" value="4">4<option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you question correct, you want to do some stuff when user selects the item from dropdown list.

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var text = $(this).val();
  alert(text);
});
```

Update: Above code will work for mobile devices also.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4j72hkuy/)

Comment: Now you do exactly what I suggested - use change. That is not what op asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$("#productlist").keydown(function(e){

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter Pressed');
    }      
  });
```

Comment: Does that work in all browsers? Will the select listen for the enter key in key down? I cannot trigger this on my mobile

Comment: Is there a browser that doesn't have enter key (except mobile) ?

Comment: Mobile was my argument

Comment: Hah :) Enter key was the premise here :)

Comment: And likely OP did not think it through :)

Comment: Where are you passing the `e` argument? :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not expected behaviour. Also it does not work on mobile devices

`on("change"` is better if there is no button to click.

You will have to add a "please select" option for that to work.

If you want to have the enter key submit, add a submit button. That will have the added value of allowing mobile and screen reader users to also use your interface

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `keypress` approach. whenever the key takes any action, it will callback. It will be work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="productlist">
            <option id="1" value="1">1</option>
            <option></option>
            <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
            <option></option>
            <option id="3" value="3">3</option>
            <option></option>
            <option id="4" value="4">4</option>
            <option></option>
        </select>

        <script>
            $("#productlist").keypress(function(){

              //for example

              console.log('Enter Pressed');
              });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```